# Dynamically Calculate Hour Sums

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the sum of multiple HTML input fields based off a type selected within a dropdown.  Basically I have multiple drop downs that look like this.

```
<select name="type1" id="type1">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="Sick">Sick</option>
    <option value="Vacation">Vacation</option>
    <option value="Holiday">Holiday</option>
    <option value="Floating Holiday">Floating Holiday</option>
    <option value="Jury Duty">Jury Duty</option>
    <option value="Bereavement">Bereavement</option>
    <option value="Suspension Paid">Suspension Paid</option>
    <option value="Suspension Unpaid">Suspension Unpaid</option>
</select>
```

I then have multiple inputs where they can put the number of PTO hours used.

```
<input name="hours1" type="text" id="hours1" size="4" maxlength="2" />
```

And then a few total fields for each type.

```
Sick:<input name="totsick" type="text" id="totsick" size="4" maxlength="2" />
Vacation:<input name="totvac" type="text" id="totvac" size="4" maxlength="2" />
```

etc.

What I want to do is dynamically calculate the sum in the total fields based off what the employee entered into the PTO hours1 field and what was selected as the type.

So if a user selects Vacation enters 8 in then the total hours field I want to dynamically update the total field for that type. There are multiple rows of inputs so if the employee selects vacation twice for two different dates I want the total to calculate the sum of each and place it in the total vacation time as 16 hours.

Comment: `name="hours1"` does not look multiple, or is it like _hours1, hours2, hours3_?

Comment: Multiple separate inputs like hours1 then another input hours2 and so on.

Comment: and what exactly is the question? did you think about doing something like: `<input name="hours[]"...` or `<input name="hours['vacation'][]..."`

Comment: Same with type1, type2, type3 etc. Multipule selections for each input of hours.  type1 hours1  type2 hours2 and so on.

Comment: I actually need an example of the code. I have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do a pure Javascript example :

```
function process() {
    var select = document.getElementById("type1");
    var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

    if (value == "Sick") {
        addTo("totsick");
    } else if (value == "Vacation") {
        addTo("totvac");
    }
}

function addTo(elId) {
    var element = document.getElementById(elId);
    var current = element.value;
    var add = document.getElementsByName("hours1")[0].value;
    alert(current+"/"+add);
    // + before for integer conversion
    element.value = +current + +add;
}
```

You can see this JSFiddle I made as an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8tcgM/)